# How to console someone whose sister has gone travelling?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, politeness, sentence-choice

Someone told me that her sister had gone to another country and she is kind of sad about this. What can I say to console her? Does "I hope she returns soon" or "I hope she comes back home soon" work?

Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Please don't post edits in comments, just click on "edit" under the tags and change the text of your question.

Answer (score 2):

I think they are both good options only if you know that your friend's sister will be returning soon(within a few months or weeks). Another option could be for you to say "I'm sure she misses you as well." This option is best used if she says that she misses her sister(who has gone to another country).

Comment: I agree @Jim, I've added an edit to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Both may not always work, because it could be possible this person is not going to come back soon.

The following is an example that seems to me to be more suitable in such cases:

> "I am so sorry and understand you, but it's not supposed to be
>   forever. We need to be happy because he is going to come back in
>   July"

If you say these statements with empathy, it may work.